# How to emit message using socket.io from two different files?

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I am working with `socket.io` , so i created server on `app.js` and connect socket to client and i see `emit('message')` is printing to the client console, Now i want to send another message from different file `consumer.js` and emit message to client but its throwing exception on server side `io.on` is not a function. Any idea what is implemented wrong in consumer.js file ?

app.js

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var consumer = require('./consumer');
var server = require('http').createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);

app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public"));

io.on('connection', function(client) {
    console.log('Client connected...');
    client.emit('message', ' hello from server');
});
server.listen(3000, function () {
    console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!');
    consumer.start();
});
```

consumer.js

```
var io = require('socket.io');
function startConsumer(consumer) {
   consumer.on('message', function (message) {
       logger.log('info', message.value);
       io.on('connection', function(client) {
           console.log('Consumer connected...');
           client.emit('Consumer-Message', 'Message from dit consumer');
       });
    });
    consumer.on('error', function (err) {
        console.log('error', err);
    });
};

exports.start = start;
```

angularCtrl.js

```
socket.on('message',function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    });
    socket.on('Consumer-Message',function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    });
```

Comment: I think that, as you do in app.js, you have to write require('socket.io')(server); in consumer.js

Comment: there must be better approach do achieve this